# How to pass same data to separately rendered ReactDom components

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm a new React user, just a few weeks into it and have just built my first app.

I have two separate parent components that are called via ReactDOM.render(). I need to have the same JSON object that's being imported via AJAX passed to both parent components.

The AJAX call currently happens in the `<Page />` component that's created. I'd like to avoid making the same call a second time for my `<Navigation />` component. I need the Navigation to remain outside the container that Page is being dumped into, which is why they are being rendered separately.

These are the two renders:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Navigation />,
  document.getElementById("navigation")
);

ReactDOM.render(
<Page url="inc/js/phoneDirectory.json" />,
    document.getElementById("content")
);
```

The AJAX call is currently in a method in the Page component. Should I move my method to the Nav component and then try to hand the data over to Page? Is this possible?

Comment: I think the best approach would be to use flux and datastores

Comment: why don't you fetch the data in the code before your `ReactDOM.render` calls?

Comment: yeah either fetch it early, or straight up make your navigation part of the Page and render in the same node. There is almost definitely a way to make those two work together.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, folks. I appreciate the help. Since I'm still working to get my head around React, and I didn't want to start jumping into learning Flux right away, I went with azium's strategy and made the Ajax call first, and then made the two ReactDOM.render calls. This worked.